# c#.net - How to go about loading forms? (suggestions)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, forms

Im just looking for suggestions on how to go about loading a form dynamically. Ive thought about two ways of doing it however both could get pretty extensive if our system ends up having a lot of forms.

**1st way** - Save the html for a form in a database and then load the html onto the page.

**2nd way** - Have a folder of all the forms and using ajax display the form.

If one of these ways is better than the other or if there is a completely better way to do this any suggustions would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question?  What exactly are you constituting as a "form?"  Just a static HTML page?  What form of end user interaction is required of the form?  How dynamic are the forms as far as maintenance/updates?  Who maintains these forms?

Comment: Was a general question on how someone may have gone about it in the past. Nothing specific, because I have this general idea in an upcoming project. And yes to clear it up, html forms, purpose is to control a whole bunch of audits that are now being done manually, and our IT Dept would be maintaining these forms.

Comment: Sounds like a good case for a product like SharePoint or Ektron.  If those are too high dollar/powerful, and security isn't a huge concern, creating a standard folder structure with these forms is a fairly easy way to approach this project.  Placing the pages/forms in a database is feasible, but you would have to create maintenance functions in order to make the product usable. Using simple iframes and setting the href to the appropriate file location would be the simplest approach.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly the kind of input I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good case for a product like SharePoint or Ektron. If those are too high dollar/powerful, and security isn't a huge concern, creating a standard folder structure with these forms is a fairly easy way to approach this project. Placing the pages/forms in a database is feasible, but you would have to create maintenance functions in order to make the product usable. Using simple iframes and setting the href to the appropriate file location would be the simplest approach.

--Copied from above since many people don't look at comments, although this seems to be a fairly broad yet specialized question.